# My array does not reset to zero after I recall the function

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a word, character, line counter for files in C. Im using a function get_counts to get these numbers. Right now I'm trying to get these values for two files. However, when I call it twice, the values don't reset to zero. I don't understand why because I declare the array to be {0,0,0} before I do any counting when I call the function. Here is my code. Currently just trying to get the line counter to work in print_counts. i'm sending it two files, one file has 3735 lines and the other file has 21. I keep getting an output of 3756.

```
int *get_counts(char *filename)
{

        FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

        if (file == NULL)
        {
                printf("NULL FILE");
                exit(1);
        }

        int c;
        bool whitespace = true;
        static int arr[3] = {0,0,0};
        for(;;)
        {
                c = fgetc(file);
                if (c == EOF)
                {
                        break;
                }
                else if (c == '\n')
                {
                        arr[0]++;
                }
                else if (whitespace && !isspace(c))
                {
                        arr[1]++;
                        whitespace = false;
                }
                else if (!whitespace && isspace(c))
                {
                        whitespace = true;
                }
                arr[2]++;
        }
        fclose(file);
        return arr;
}
void print_counts(int* show, int *count, char *name)
        {
                if (name[0] != '\0')
                {
                        //int *myArray1 = get_counts(&name[0]);
                        if (show[0] == 1)
                        {
                                printf("%d", count[0]);
                        }
                }
                if (name[1] != '\0')
                {
                        if (show[0] == 1)
                        {
                                printf("%d", count[0]);
                        }
                }
        }
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int argArray[argc];
        char *nameArray[argc];


        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i ++)
        {
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "-l") == 0)
                {
                        argArray[0] = 1;
                }
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "-w") == 0)
                {
                        argArray[1] = 1;
                }
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "-c") == 0)
                {
                        argArray[2] = 1;
                }
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "alice.txt") == 0)
                {
                        nameArray[0] = "alice.txt";
                }
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "anh.txt") == 0)
                {
                        nameArray[1] = "anh.txt";
                }

                if ((strcmp(argv[i], "-l") != 0) && (strcmp(argv[i], "-c") != 0 ) && (strcmp(argv[i], "-w") != 0 ) && (strcmp(argv[i], "-w") != 0) && (strcmp(argv[i], "alice.txt") != 0) && (strcmp(argv[i], "anh.txt") != 0))
                {
                        printf("error");
                        exit(1);
                }
        }
        int *myArrayAlice = get_counts(nameArray[0]);
        print_counts(argArray, myArrayAlice, *nameArray);
        int *myArrayAnh = get_counts(nameArray[1]);
        print_counts(argArray, myArrayAnh, *nameArray);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why because I declare the array to be {0,0,0}
> before I do any counting when I call the function.

Because is defined as `static`, remove the `static` keyword switching to `int *arr = calloc(3, sizeof(int);` or passing `arr[3]` from `main` and calling `memset(arr, 0, 3 * sizeof(int));` in the function if you prefer to avoid dynamic memory.

Comment: I tried that and I get a warning that function returns address of local variable